# When and why does an away-team member wear native clothing during negotiation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, clothing

In "Angel One," Commander Riker dons the clothing of Angel I before negotiating with Mistress Beata.

He tells a snickering Deanna Troi and Tasha Yar, "On Kabatris, I had to wear furs to meet with the leadership council, and on Armus IX I wore feathers."

Is it basically an issue of appealing to the wishes of his audience? Or is there a reason why an away-team leader may wish to don the native clothing?

This issue doesn't come up very often, so I assume that these particular worlds were really strict and had high opinions of themselves.

[image: Riker wearing native clothing, exposing a large part of his chest]

Comment: Check out the following link as it explains a lot of the backstory behind the concepts and vision Roddenberry used when creating the themes portrayed and demonstrated throughout the franchise specifically those of TNG https://books.google.com/books?id=dWBfAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT257&lpg=PT257&dq=star+trek+away+teams+negotiating+treaties&source=bl&ots=oEh0I9kcxE&sig=ACfU3U1Sjcsouwze285y-gzs3UjEVA5XGQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzrIHT6qrgAhULcq0KHaXEBtMQ6AEwF3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=negotiating%20treaties&f=false

Comment: I'm not reading all of that!

Comment: Since there was no actual definite answer I extrapolated my best educated guess using that reference and others based on multiple documentaries, books and even licensed video games. I am a huge Trekkie so for me it was a great read. If you choose not to do so then I hope you can accept that I at least tried to find the relevant data and supply the results of my research. I won’t claim it as the gospel but I would like to think the answer I gave is as close to accurate as I can provide without spending a lot more time researching than I currently have available.

Comment: Angel One is also from first season. First season is really inconsistent with the other seasons.

Answer (score 5):

I think you missed what Riker said immediately before. He intends for this to be a *diplomatic* mission. That includes honouring the host's traditions.

> **TROI:** *You're not going to wear that.*
>
> **RIKER:** *Of course. **Part of this mission is diplomatic. I have requested an audience with a head of state, and I will honour her by
>   wearing indigenous apparel.***

There are multiple examples of Picard doing this when making overtures to alien leaders.

[image: Picard wearing white clothing with the Starfleet insignia visible, as well as a black beaded headdress that hangs down on either side of his head]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that last one is clothing they wore on the holodeck (20th century Earth program), not clothing appropriate to the alien species.

Comment: @jaxad0127 - The *clothing* is holodeck period appropriate (to Picard's "Dixon Hill" holo-novel), but the alien-language speech, that he's very carefully prepared, is the diplomacy bit that I was referring to when I said that the senior crew often honour their host's traditions

Comment: The question is about clothing. I see nothing about language.

Comment: @jaxad0127 - My answer was answering the more general point about observing the traditions of the host in diplomatic and [ceremonial](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/7/72/Picard_cha%27dich.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20161209212208&path-prefix=en) situations. That includes clothing, language and [religious observation](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/1/18/Opaka_Sisko.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20060604210046&path-prefix=de)